# Error in reducing space between chapters in summary

Tags: tocloft

I need to remove the vertical space between chapters in my summary, I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               
    oneside,                
    a4paper,            
    chapter=TITLE,      
    section=TITLE,      
    subsection=title,   
    subsubsection=title,
    brazil              
    ]{abntex2}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section Two}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Last Chapter}

\end{document}
```

This is the result i am getting:

[image]

But I am getting 3 errors. What am I doing wrong here? All the spaces should be like the one between Introduction and Section One.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this class uses memoir. `memoir` command is `\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}`, a little different from the `tocloft` package, which needn't be loaded.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section Two}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Last Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The example below should give a head start

With `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}` commented out

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
% \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section Two}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\chapter{Last Chapter}

\end{document}
```

the result is

[image]

And if you enable `\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}` by removing the comment `%` the result is

[image]

I have changed the `\documentclass`

Please see if it helps

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info. But unfortunately, changing the document class it's not possible at this point.

Comment: One of the experts on the site will assist you--for me the documentation is a foreign language